# Removing the data from USB in ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, permissions, mount

I Just Copied some Directories to my USB and now i am trying to Restore them back in their Orginal places, Whenever i tried to remove them from the usb, It's not showing the option to do so; and i also tried to Change the permissions for the directories in the usb, but it's still not removing them from the USB.

Commands i have tried 
`mkdir /media/usb/`
 `mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb/`
`cd /media/usb`
And now i am running this `sudo chmod -R a+rwx /media/usb` but when it was still showing the **read only** access to ***group users*** then i run
`sudo chmod g+wr /media/usb` , and i tried all the possible ways that i found on this webpage https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions.
**NOTE: I Have also run these all commands with root permission (`Sudo su`)**
But still not working :(

Comment: What is the file system on the USB? Check the integrity of it. If ntfs, then have the drive checked under MS Windows. Linux may mount file systems that are not 'clean' read only to prevent futher damage.

Comment: Did you know that USB sticks inserted into a running Ubuntu (Desktop) version will automatically show up at `/media/<username>/<name of USB stick>`? No need to `sudo mount` 'yourself'. Also, the commands you're trying are for Unix/Linux type filesystems, which usually are **not** the filesystems used on USB sticks. In other words, FAT32 and NTFS (which are prevalent on USB sticks) are unaware of (users and) groups - so **`sudo chmod` will not even work**! Eject the stick, reinsert it, go over to `/media/<your username>/<USB name>` and start erasing the files you have put back on your harddisk.

Comment: @Adriaan I have tried your solution and i am i went to the directory **/media/akrambhat/7C21-1604/** but now its again unable to overwrite the data.

Comment: @vanadium the usb integrity is ntfs32. How can i **clean** this

Answer (score 0):

### How to check your USB storage device for errors

(after it was mounted automatically but you mounted it again elsewhere, causing it to be incorrectly ejected):

Insert your USB device, then wait a little. Start a terminal and type:

```
lsblk -f
```

Note the device name in the first column of the line with `/media/<username>/<USBname>`, for example `sdd` and `sdd1`. We'll call this `/dev/sdX1`. Next look for the filesystemtype: probably ntfs or vfat.

Now, unmount (not eject) the USB device:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdX1
```

(replace the X with your device letter, don't forget the 1 if `lsblk` had it, and **do** take care, please **do** make sure - it's easy to break the whole system being careless and using `sudo`).

### vfat

Check the system with:

```
sudo fsck.vfat -a /dev/sdX1
```

(and repeat this until no more errors are found)

### ntfs

Check the system with:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdX1
```

This command may not be able to get rid of all errors - if it doesn't, consider rescuing whatever is on the USB device and reformat it (maybe using `sudo gparted`?)